# how should i add projects without main method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, solution

I'm trying to implement
[this "hello world" example](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html)
for `asp.net` core with `Entity framework`.

After doing the example i tried split it to 2 projects. one for model, and the other for API.

I created 2 project in same solution, deleted the `startup.cs`, `program.cs` from the second. added model to the second, and registered the model in the first.

When trying to build - I got error

> Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry
>   point entities

I tried look for docs about working with multiple projects, but didnt found. Maybe I dont know the Professional terms.

How should I add projects without main method?

10x!

I tried again with 2 projects both with `startup.cs` and `program.cs`, then the build succeeded, but when trying to run on nuget console: "Add-Migration MyFirstMigration", I got

> No parameterless constructor was found on BloggingContext

. Either add a parameterless constructor to `BloggingContext` or add an implementation of `IDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>` in the same assembly as `BloggingContext`."

what should i do?

thanks again.

Comment: U can create a class library project that will give us the dll and we use class using this dll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be only one startup project in your solution. If you want to create project for your models, Create a **`class library`** instead of console/web/window application.

1. Right click on your solution
2. Add -> New Project
3. Select Class Library and give nice name and click on OK button.
4. Add reference of that class library project in your main project

See below image:

[image: Create Class Library]

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you added the second project as a console project, not a class library. If you don't want it to be standalone executable you should use that instead.

**You can still change your second project to not be standalone**, by changing the project properties (right click on the project > Properties), and changing the output type to class library.

The parameterless constructor issue sounds unrelated. You've probably added a constructor with a parameter, or are inheriting from a class with no parameterless constructor, that requires you to supply values to the base constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your first error, but I encountered your **second** error by forgetting to add my DB context in Startup.cs:

`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}`

Alternatively, [these docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#error-no-parameterless-constructor-was-found) refer to that error and advise using a [IDbContextFactory](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#use-idbcontextfactory) instead.